# Syntax error in database

Tags: android, database

In my application  i created a database(before with group field it works fine).Now i want to cretae one more field(called group).I created that field .But showing the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error: create table incomexpense(_id integer primary key autoincrement,price text not null,description text not null,quantity text not null,total text not null,category text not null,recurrence text not null,date text not null,group text not null);
```

My create command:

```
"create table incomexpense(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+"price text not null,description text not null,"+"quantity text not null,"+"total text not null,"+"category text not null,"+"recurrence text not null,"+"date text not null,"+"group text not null);";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`group` is a keyword so it should not be used while creating a table.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It works fine..I am little bit new to android and this database concepts...

Comment: @Prakash, you should accept this answer (click the check mark next to it).  That will let everyone know your issue has been solved and give some recognition to the person that helped you.